# want to ensure tty write is pushed to hardware (UART) by a given timestamp or fails

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to write some data to a serial port whilst ensuring that if it can't be written by a given 'expiry timestamp' that it will return failure code. The data comes from a different serial port, and the expiry time from a 3rd device.

My original plan was to implement all of this in kernelspace, but I concluded that since it needs access to 3 devices it'd probably be better to bridge them in userspace; that unfortunately makes the timing difficult.

Despite spending some significant time reading LDD3 and looking through tty subsystem and related code, I'm having trouble working out how to achieve this. I effectively want to add functionality to an existing serial port/tty device so that I can use ioctl or write an escape sequence indicating the data and expiry time.

I have control over the kernel source here, though since it's already been distributed if I can achieve this solely with a kernel module that would be superb. If reflashing the kernel is essential then so be it.

Can anyone provide either guidance on adding this expiring-write to existing serial/tty combination, or other advice on what might be a better way to go about this?

Thanks in advance - apologies if not enough info, I'll add details if they're required.

Comment: How precise is the control you're looking for? If the serial chip has automatic flow control, bytes could be written into the hardware FIFO and then wait indefinitely to be released by the other end.

Comment: It's the local end, not the remote end that knows whether tha data can be sent out or not, but I guess the serial driver could be enhanced to provide that functionality. Good move?

Comment: Have you checked if tcdrain() or TIOCOUTQ ioctl (man tty_ioctl) could be used to implement the needed functionality in userspace?

Comment: @kappi - not sure whether they will help - they provide information after the write() as to the transmission state, but can't help to ensure the transmission timing is as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose doing this entirely in userspace. There are two assumptions behind this: you don't have flow control, and the precision required is around 50ms or worse.

The lack of flow control is essential: hardware flow control can allow a hostile remote device to cheat you, by stalling bytes within the UART FIFO. Software flow control can stall data in the device driver. With that out of the way, data will flow through the UART at the required baud rate without delay. If you ensure that the kernel buffers are empty before each write to the device, you will achieve your timing.

The parts of my solution are:

1. Run your application using `SCHED_FIFO` to avoid pre-emption.
2. Select a message to send. You don't say if there is an ordering constraint on your messages. If there isn't, you may want to implement a scheduler to decide the message order. Earliest deadline first would probably work.
3. Always `tcdrain` before writing.
4. Once you know the output buffer is empty, check that there is enough time for all the bytes to travel at the selected baud rate. If there is insufficient time remaining, emit the failure code and return to the top.
5. Write the message bytes.

To handle the other ports you'll need to use multiple threads or `select` with timeouts. If you use `select`, remember that your thread will be blocked in `tcdrain`.

And if you need much more precise timing consider using a dedicated microcontroller.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me. If flow control is used, the sender can't be 100% certain if the deadline will be met before all of the data has been written. Ie. the transfer may start but may be blocked due to flow control which may cause uenxpected delay.

Comment: Superb - I wasn't aware of the sched_setscheduler() call, but since 50ms is fine and there's no flow control that looks just like what I need. I'm pleased I can achieve this in userspace, makes it a lot easier (and safer!) Thanks for the thorough detail too, much appreciated.